# Change Values on my plist iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have a .plist with one array and in this array i have some NSDictionary in it.
Now I want to change in my Dictionary some Values.
My Idea is to load the whole array, find the value, change it, and write over the whole array.
but it cost a lot of time.
Do you know a better way to change special values.

Comment: Its impossible to tell what your performance issue is without posting some code.

Comment: I dont have a performance Problem its more a alternative problem.

Comment: Is this a bundled plist? Keep in mind that it's read only and that you'll have to store it somewhere in order to modify it.

Comment: oh okay, I have a plist with datas from beginning now i want that the list is not bundled how can i Handle it...

Comment: Create a dictionary and use NSDictionary's writeToFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to persist data using a .plist, there's no alternative than to write out the whole file if you make a change.

An alternative for storing large amounts of data that would allow you to update individual records would be to use CoreData - which is effectively a database stored on the device.

Core Data is a lot more complicated than using a plist, but more scalable, and all the other benefits that come with using a database.

Answer (score 2):

There's no time issue here. Let's talk big-O notation:

1. Worst case cost of fetching an NSDictionary from the array: **O(log(n))** - [source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/Articles/types.html)
2. Worst case cost of fetching a value from within the dictionary: **O(log(n))** (see above source)
3. Cost of performing any constant amount of operations on that value within the dictionary **O(c)**

O(log(n))+O(log(n))+O(c)=**O(log(n))**

So you are 'stuck' with O(log(n)) which isn't bad at all.

Answer (score -1):

How big is the plist? How often do you do it? It shouldn't be a performance problem..

Comment: its not a big one, but I thought there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Nah, that's pretty much always how it's done. Try it and measure. If it's too slow, the best alternative may be a database, for example sqlite.